# Как адаптировать таблицу на сайте без скрола?

Tags: html, css

Сайт:https://simfer-taxi.ru/tarify/
Как можно адаптировать таблицу на нем без скрола?

Comment: Это я раньше задал

Answer (score 1):

- убрать фиксированную ширину первой колонки;
- добавить пробелы перед скобками;
- уменьшить шрифт до 12рх;
- скрыть названия  классов авто.

Если все это сделать, тогда таблица получится около 300px в ширину - должна влезть во все современные телефоны.